# Change the location of Nuxt progress bar

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs

I'm using Nuxt with Vuetify so may layout is navbar on the top and a menu on the left.
is it possible to move the progress bar at the top of the actual page it self (below the navbar)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The loading bar is very customisable but not as far as changing its location.

But you can create your own component that will replace the default loading bar, so that you can make it appear everywhere. It's a little bit more works to do though.
See the [official docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/#using-a-custom-loading-component).

Comment: how can I set its position in relation to other component/page?

Comment: I tested some things, but turns out you can't control where to place the loading component it the components tree. Nuxt instanciate it itself as the first component under <Root>. Maybe you could open a feature request for this?

Answer (score 0):

The loading bar is customizable in nuxt.config.js, there you can change the following properties:

[available properties for nuxt.config.js loading object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZxcF.png)

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-loading

I had a project where i needed to change the loading bar color & height by using only css and not messing around with nuxt.config.js. So i just opened the source of the rendered site and looked for .nuxt-progress and found the following default styles:

```
.nuxt-progress {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: width 0.1s, opacity 0.4s;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 999999;
}
.nuxt-progress.nuxt-progress-notransition {
  transition: none;
}
.nuxt-progress-failed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

So i just overwrote those styles with css and !important flags, and it just worked. So i guess you should be able to change position and rotation of the loading bar so it loads from top to bottom or bottom to top on the left side of the viewport. I've read that you can just change the component completely and that might just be the best way to customizing it, rather than overwriting the default .nuxt-progress css.

https://nuxtjs.org/examples/custom-loading-component/